# How to mock private methods without using PrepareFor annotation in PowerMock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, powermock, jacoco

I am trying to generate Code coverage report using JaCoCo. My company is specific that I must use only JaCoCo. Unfortunately there is a test case where I need to use PowerMock to mock a private method. So I have to use @PrepareFor annotation and the @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) annotation. When I try to generate report in gradle using gradle clean build jacocoTestReport, the code coverage doesn't cover this test case due to the annotations.
Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: There is a [bugreport](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/422) with PowerMock ... for many months. I wouldn't hold my breath on that to be fixed any time soon. One of the many reasons to not use PowerMock.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

- Use offline JaCoCo instrumentation as it described [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Code-coverage-with-JaCoCo). For Gradle example you may find [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/jacoco-offline-instrumentation-in-gradle/9996/2)
- Try to use [ByteBuddy](http://bytebuddy.net/) and redefine a class which contains the private method and add handler for the method. ByteBuddy is different from Javassist, that it work with loaded, already instrumented by JaCoCo, classes.

Comment: I will check it out and let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got coverage with PowerMockito but I do not think it will work in all cases. It will only work if the class to be tested has a super class. Let me explain.

This might be the class you want to test

```
class ClassToBeTested extends/implements SuperClass/interface {
//Code 

}
```

For example, if you want to write a Unit test for the class called "ClassToBeTested" and it has some private methods or constructors that must be mocked. So typically you will try to use PowerMockito for mocking the private methods and it would roughly look like something below.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassToBeTested.class)
class ClassToBeTestedTest {
//Lots or some test code here 

}
```

Now you will not get code coverage for "ClassToBeTested". But in the PrepareForTest annotation, if we use the superclass or the interface being implemented by the class-to-be-tested instead of the original class like below.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SuperClass.class)
class ClassToBeTestedTest {
//Lots or some test code here 

}
```

I got code-coverage for this. But this will work only if your classToBeTested has some superclass. It is just a quick and dirty fix but not a perm. solution for everyone.

Comment: Thanks !. What we should be doing if the class doesn't have super classs to generate the code coverage ?

Comment: @Sayali Well you cannot do much. If powermock is the only way to test your code then the code itself isn't very good. On the other hand, if you want to get codeCoverage, see if your code has any exception scenarios and try to simulate that. Make sure you do not do that in the same test class where you written the "PrepareForTest" annotation, it wont work. Create a separate test class for this exception case and simulate it.